# Can't import numpy module into python file, but it works with terminal

Tags: python, numpy, ubuntu-18.04

On Ubuntu I have python 3.6.9

I created new project using PyCharm, into project folder there is `venv` folder.
When I open `venv` folder in terminal and do:

```
python3
import numpy
```

It works, no any error.

But when I create some file in that `venv` folder using PyCharm, and  try in this file:

```
import numpy
```

then I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'` error.

Why can't import module into file? module obviously installed because I can import that using terminal (folder is same for both cases).

What is my mistake ?

Comment: Do you use a different version of python on PyCharm ?

Comment: @SurajSubramanian - in  pycharm 
`import sys 
print(sys.version)` gives:  3.6.9

Comment: @SurajSubramanian -  in terminal exactly same version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pycharm** uses virtual environments for serving modules, so you will have to download the package from either the GUI or by activating the virtual environment in the terminal and then doing the pip install.

if you want to do it from the **GUI** you can check the official [tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html). (Working and tested)

To do it manually, first to activate the environment in **linux** go wherever the venv folder is and type `source  venv/scripts/activate` (to activate) and then you'll be able to do `pip install numpy`. (Not tested but it should work)

Comment: Thank you, it seems I missed   virtual environment activation, after that, imported module into file, without problem

Answer (score 0):

Could you share your Pycharm configuration?
Some extra steps are needed in Pycharm to configure venv, otherwise it will just take your normal interpreter site-packages.

Take a look at the Pycharm help page: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html#existing-environment

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need to install numpy through pip3.
Also, check which version of python is running in pycharm.